# i am trying to fetch audio files from my phone but my app is unable to fetch the files ,for that i wrote this line of code help me to find solution

Tags: android

this is my depndency i used dexter library for runtime permission request.

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
`implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'` 
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

}
`method to store audio file in array`

```
public ArrayList<File> findSong(File file) {
ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
File[] files = file.listFiles();
for (File singleFile : files) {
if (singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()) {
arrayList.addAll(findSong(singleFile));
} else {
if (singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || 
singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav")) {
arrayList.add(singleFile);
}
}
}
return arrayList;
```

}
methode for store audio formatted

```
public void displaySong() {
 final ArrayList<File> mySongs = 
 findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
 items = new String[mySongs.size()];
 for (int i = 0; i < mySongs.size(); i++) {
 items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace("mp3", 
 "").replace(".wav", "");
     }
 customAdapter cu = new customAdapter();
 listView.setAdapter(cu);
```

}
my custom adapter

```
class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);
        TextView txtSong = myView.findViewById(R.id.txtSong);
        txtSong.setSelected(true);
        txtSong.setText(items[i]);
        return myView;
    }
}
```

runtime permission method

```
public void runTimePermission() {
    Dexter.withContext(this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                    displaySong();

                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                    permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();

                }
            }).check();
}
```

main Activty

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
String[] items;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSong);
    runTimePermission();


}
```

after installing when i try to run this app it asks for the storage permission but does not load all audio files from my device.
in build section i found `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings`i tried to run gradel with `--warning-mode all` but nothing has come out with this my build   keep showing me this`Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings` help me to find any solution. i have also taken the permission in `manifest`.

Comment: Which audio files are not found? Full paths please.

Comment: Only function findSong() is relevant. Please remove all other code as that has nothing to do with not finding files.

Comment: `to display in listview` i have created display method.

Comment: Can be, but that has nothing to do with finding files. So its irrelevant. I wonder why you reacted in this way. Come to the point please.

Comment: My point is why my audio file is not fetching from my device. if i am doing this in emulator its working fine but when it come to use in my phone app gets crash.

Comment: please suggest me better way to do this...

Comment: I am really a new member with this.. I can't understand what you want me to explain... Can you please guide me to make my code correct so i can run it in my device.. It is running good in emulator but not in my phone.

Comment: `I can't understand what you want me to explain... ` Pretty strange that you do not understand what i want you to do. Repeat: `Please remove all other code as that has nothing to do with not finding files.`.

Comment: i have removed that and now i am getting this warning.-->```The RepositoryHandler.jcenter() method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. JFrog announced JCenter's shutdown in February 2021. Use mavenCentral() instead. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#jcenter_deprecation```